# Why isn't the ViewPager infinite loop not working?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-adapter

So I have this carousel project that shows a set number of pictures in a carousel way through a ViewPager. Before getting to this point, I had test the functionality of the ViewPager by manualy putting pictures and info in a mutable list, and it worked. Now doing that with the info coming from an API, it doesn't seem to work anymore. I haven't changed anything when it comes to the actual functions that control the loop either.

The Adapter

```
class CarouselItemAdapter internal constructor (info: MutableList<CarouselItem>,viewPager2: ViewPager2) : ListAdapter<CarouselItem,CarouselItemAdapter.CarouselViewHolder>(DiffCallback) {
    private val viewPager2: ViewPager2
    private var info: MutableList<CarouselItem>

    companion object DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<CarouselItem>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: CarouselItem, newItem: CarouselItem): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: CarouselItem, newItem: CarouselItem): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }

    }

    init {
        this.viewPager2 = viewPager2
        this.info = info

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): CarouselViewHolder {
       return CarouselViewHolder(CustomContainerBinding.inflate(
           LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
           parent, false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CarouselViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position))
        if (position == info.size - 2) {
            viewPager2.post(runnable)
        }
    }


    class CarouselViewHolder(private val binding: CustomContainerBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){
        fun bind(item: CarouselItem){
            binding.parts = item
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }
    }


    private val runnable = Runnable {
        info.addAll(info)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun addAll(items: MutableList<CarouselItem>) {
        info = items
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }


}
```

The Fragment

```
class MainFragment: Fragment() {

//    private lateinit var manager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager

    private lateinit var viewModel: MainFragmentViewModel
    private lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager2
    private var counter: Int = 0
    private var pageChangeCallback: ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback? = null


    var data: MutableList<CarouselItem> = ArrayList()


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding: MainFragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater,
            R.layout.main_fragment,
            container, false)

        val mainViewModelFactory = MainFragmentViewModelFactory(requireActivity().application)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, mainViewModelFactory).get(MainFragmentViewModel::class.java)

        binding.viewModel = viewModel

        viewPager = binding.imageSlider

//
//        val data: MutableList<CarouselItem> = ArrayList()
//        data.add(CarouselItem(1, "bcw_65", "First"))
//        data.add(CarouselItem(2, "bcw_66", "Second"))
//        data.add(CarouselItem(3, "bcw_67", "Third"))
//        data.add(CarouselItem(4, "bcw_68", "Fourth"))
//        data.add(CarouselItem(5, "bcw_69", "Fifth"))
//        data.add(CarouselItem(6, "bcw_70", "Sixth"))
//        data.add(CarouselItem(2, "bcw_71", "Seventh"))

        val adapter = CarouselItemAdapter(data, viewPager)

        viewPager.adapter = adapter

        viewModel.picInfo.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            adapter.addAll(data)
            adapter.submitList(it)
        })




        viewPager.clipToPadding = false
        viewPager.clipChildren = false
        viewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 3
        viewPager.getChildAt(0).overScrollMode = RecyclerView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER

        val compositePageTransformer = CompositePageTransformer()
        compositePageTransformer.addTransformer(MarginPageTransformer(30))
        compositePageTransformer.addTransformer { page, position ->
            val r = 1 - abs(position)
            page.scaleY = 0.85f + r * 0.25f
        }

        viewPager.setPageTransformer(compositePageTransformer)

        createChannel(
            getString(R.string.carousel_notification_id),
            getString(R.string.app_name)

        )


        val notificationManager = ContextCompat.getSystemService(
            requireContext(),
            NotificationManager::class.java,
        ) as NotificationManager




        //Used to count the number of swipes bing called
        viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                counter++
                binding.counterView.text = counter.toString()
                if((counter % 20) == 0) {
                    notificationManager.sendNotification(
                        requireContext().getText(R.string.swipe_description).toString(), requireContext())
                }
            }
        }.also { pageChangeCallback = it })



        return binding.root
    }

    //Needed to destroy the pageChangeCallback
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        viewPager.unregisterOnPageChangeCallback(pageChangeCallback!!)
        pageChangeCallback = null
    }

    private fun createChannel (channelID: String, channelName: String){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(
                channelID,
                channelName,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )

            notificationChannel.enableLights(true)
            notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.WHITE
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true)
            notificationChannel.description = getString(R.string.swipe_description)

            val notificationManager = requireActivity().getSystemService(
                NotificationManager::class.java
            )

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
        }
    }


}
```

I'm pretty sure it is a simple reason behind it and I'm just not seeing it. Any ideas at all will be more than welcomed.

Comment: "it doesn't seem to work anymore", can you be a bit more specific? does it crash your app? does it not show any images? are the images displayed in the wrong order?

Comment: The app does run and It shows the images as well. It just doesn't loop as a carousel like I had initially done it. Just shows the X amount of pictures I requested.

Answer (score 0):

you init adapter with empty `Arraylist` and Runnable in adapter always operates with empty list `info`
it is better to use item list inside adapter as a single source of truth:

```
viewModel.picInfo.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            // dont need to call notifyDatasetChanges() as diffutil will do the work
            val newList = adapter.info.plus(it)
            adapter.submitList(newList) { adapter.info = newList }
        })
```

Comment: I might be misinterpreting what you were explaining a little bit. I created an items variable where it was assigned as a MutableList<CarouselItem>. Then I was able to code it in the same way as above and It got it to go through the picture carousel, 2 times (seeing the 15 pictures twice). Was the way I did it what you were talking about?

Comment: I wrote it wrong, you can use the variable `info` inside adapter (by changing its visibility). I corrected the answer.

Comment: Alright. I am still getting the same results as I previously stated as well as the carousel not starting at the beginning, but somewhere in the middle.